# Is there a better way to code a get_all model method in Codeigniter?

Tags: model, codeigniter-2

I am working on a Course Task Manager model in Codeigniter and I'm trying to find out what else can I do to improve the get_all method.

Is this a good way of doing it (see code below)? The reason I concat some values is because I'm trying to do less work in the controller. Is this ok?

So far the Task manager uses 4 tables - users, tasks, task_types(edit, review etc) and courses

Here's the code

```
function get_tasks(){

    $query = $this->db->query(' 
    SELECT 

            tasks.id,
            tasks.created,
            tasks.expires,

            types.name as type,
            courses.name as course,

            CONCAT_WS(" ", assigned_by.first_name, assigned_by.last_name) as assigned_by,
            CONCAT_WS(" ", users.first_name, users.last_name) as user

        FROM
            '.$this->tables['tasks'].' tasks
        LEFT JOIN 
            '.$this->tables['types'].' types ON (types.id = tasks.type_id)
        LEFT JOIN 
            '.$this->tables['users'].' assigned_by ON (assigned_by.id = tasks.assigned_by_id)
        LEFT JOIN 
            '.$this->tables['users'].' users ON (users.id = tasks.user_id)
        LEFT JOIN 
            '.$this->tables['courses'].' courses ON (courses.id = tasks.course_id)

        ORDER BY 
            tasks.created ASC'
    ); 

    return $query->result();

}
```

This is how I call the the method in the controller:

```
$this->load->model('Task_model', 'task');

$this->data['tasks'] = $this->task->get_tasks();
```

Comment: please tell us clearly what you want?

Comment: Your query looks fine from here. Some may suggest to use ActiveRecord to recreate your query, however this would be quicker (marginly.) It's more down to your personal taste on this one I think.

Comment: I was looking for the best way to define a get all method in CI. Do I name it get_all, get_tasks, just maybe tasks. What is the standard? So I provided an example of what I have so far and asked for an opinion. The query could be written with active records but I am not sure yet how to do CONCAT in it. Another question could be: Is it the role of the model to do stuff like CONCAT.